# How to calculate the number of parameters in CNN when dealing with pictures

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I get a question as follows:

> Suppose you have a 10x10x3 colour image input and you want to stack
>   two convolutional layers with kernel size 3x3 with 10 and 20 filters
>   respectively. How many parameters do you have to train for these two
>   layers?

And I know how to solve a one convolutional layer situation that the number of parameters should be `(filter.shape[0]*filter.shape[1]*...*filter.shape[n] + bias) * number of filters`.
But I am not sure about how to calculate the number of parameters in multi-layers situations.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add all the parameters from each layer. You have the formula for one layer:

(filter.shape[0]*filter.shape[1]*...*filter.shape[n] + bias) * number of filters

So just calculate this for each layer and add up.

In your example this would give (exlcuding bias):

**Layer 1 #params = 3x3x3x10 parameters**

**Layer 2 #params = 3x3x10x20 parameters**

Total = Layer 1 #params + Layer 2 #params

Comment: you forgot the bias terms. Each kernel/filter has one bias. (Irrespective of number of channels in kernel, there is only one bias per kernel). Correct answer is provided by @Q-01

Answer (score 11):

After the first layer you have 10 channels instead of 3.

Given the input is 3x3 with depth 3 and 10 filters it results in (3*3*3+1)*10 parameters.

But in the second layer the depth is 10, cause of the first layer. So it becomes (3*3*10+1)*20

(3*3*3+1)*10 + (3*3*10+1)*20 = 2100

Comment: Hello, may I know why is the depth 10 for second layer?Can you kindly help me to understand it?reference or documentation will be useful

Comment: @jay depth is 10 for second layer because the first layer outputs 10 channels (one channel for each of the kernels in the first layer, as each kernel makes its own channel). So then the kernels in the second layer need 10 channels, one for each of the channels in layer 2's input (which is layer 1's output).